# Подлинная правда

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Подлинный — значит истинный, настоящий, без подлога; подлинник — оригинал, авторский экземпляр, опять же связан со словом "правда".
А вот почему подлинный? Это слово напоминает слово "подлый", что логически совершенно не вяжется со значением слова "подлинный".
Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему синоним слова "истинный" — это "подлинный"?

Answer (score 4):

Об этимологии слова "подлинный" можно услышать в лекции А. А.Зализняка [вот здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLGcD1ACbZo&t=1h19m18s).

Это слово действительно родственно слову "подлый" и имеет исторический корень "под(л)", а вот корня "длин" здесь никакого нет, иначе не было бы устойчивого ударения на "о". У слова "подлый" изначальное значение - "нижний, низкий". В "Словаре русских народных говоров" и в словаре Даля есть слово "по́длина" со значением "подкладка". Слово "подлинный" вначале применялось исключительно к грамотам, и возможно (здесь уже идут предположения), что существовал некий процесс копирования, при котором оригинал располагался под копией.

Comment: Интересно! Действительно, подличать значит унижаться.)

Answer (score 0):

Этимология слова "подлинный" достоверна неизвестна, но к "подлости" отношения точно не имеет. Скорее всего тут исторический корень "длин", а "по" - приставка. "Подлинниками" в старину на Руси называли длинные шесты. Этими шестами при случае и пытали жертву с целью выведать "подлинную" правду. Фасмер уже это считает достаточным основанием для версии употребления "подлинный" в значении "истинный". 
(+)
Аналогичная версия и у Семенова.

(++) Во избежание повторения Грумантом удаления критики.
Да мало ли где что расположено было в 1700 лохматом году. 
Надо ж немного и научными взглядами оперировать, а не только доморощенной "какбынетно-спинджачной" этимологией.
И какой смысл заливать сюда словообильную цитату из Фасмера по поводу совершенно дркгого слова если сам Фасмер придерживается совершенно другой версии на этимологию "подлинника"? А про "подлый" даже не упоминает?

Answer (score -1):

«Узнать всю подноготную» – история этого древнерусского присловья тоже связана с пыткой – на Руси дознавались до правды, выдирая у подозреваемых ногти или же загоняя под них иглы. «Подлинный» – это слово также является производным от обозначения пыточного процесса – «добытый под линькой» (линька – веревочная плеть, которой секли моряков).

Comment: А посмотреть пару минут лекции А. Зализняка по ссылке выше? Слово "подлинник" появилось в языке на 600 лет раньше этих верёвок.